# ionic cli - export project from 'Creator' not working

Tags: ionic-framework

I've created a test project using ionic creator. I've created a blank page, assigned a title and added a button.

I save the project and I'd like to export the project

---

**Ionic Creator - Using CLI**

When I use the Ionic CLI tool with the command

```
ionic start [appName] creator:[MY_ID]
```

It tries to download my project from the following URL:

https://apps.ionic.io/api/v1/creator/[MY_ID]/download/html

This returns an empty zip file. So my project doesn't get initialised.

---

**Ionic Creator - ZIP Export**

The ZIP file link in creator is the following URL:

https://creator.ionic.io/api/v1/creator/[MY_ID]/download/html

This does return a ZIP with what I expect in.

---

I have successfully checked out a project using the CLI ~2 weeks ago and can't see what I'm doing differently. I'd be interested to know if anyone else is experiencing this problem?

I've tried putting the ZIP file contents into the WWW folder and initialising that way but to no avail.

- CLI version is 1.7.1
- OS is Windows 7

I have updated both the CLI and Cordova to the latest version.

Any ideas?

**Note:** I've raised this as a GitHub issue too - https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues/619

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've upgraded from 1.7.1 to 1.7.6 today and it's now working.

It's using the following URL now -

https://creator.ionic.io/api/v1/creator/[ID]/download-start/cordova?sid=[SID]

Comment: Hey I am new to ionic I am getting any option of ionic CLI while exporting the project . Can you please help from where I can get this option?